# Libre Writer recognises 'Garamond' font when loading a document written in it, but does not have it as a selection

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I am using Ubuntu 14, and am loading at Word .doc text file template provided by CreateSpace[link](https://www.createspace.com/). The text in this template uses a font called *Garamond*. When I put a cursor over text in the template the name of the font appears, and when I type more text when this font is selected I am able to.

The problem is that I cannot write new text in this *Garamond* font, because it is not given as an option in the font drop down list. In a new document I cannot find this name, although I can find EB Garamond etc. I have installed from the Ubuntu software centre Microsoft fonts, and have installed at the command line various other fonts.

I would like to convert my text into *Garamond* before pasting the text into the template, but can only do so if there is an option to convert the font to the correct one before.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When foreign documents use an unknown font you don't have installed, that font's name still gets displayed in LibreOffice Writer, but it automatically picks one of your installed fonts that it thinks is most similar to what you might want to see.

So what you describe is the perfectly normal and intended behavior in the situation that you just don't have any font called *Garamond* installed.
Note that the substitiution is done by LibreOffice and not by Ubuntu.

As the original *Garamond* font is not free available, chances are low that you will ever encounter them in any Ubuntu repository.

However, you may find a free clone of the Garamond fonts, *EB-Garamont* to [download here](https://bitbucket.org/georgd/eb-garamond/downloads), but note that it is a project which is still in development.

For instructions on how to install font files to your Ubuntu system, please visit the question [How do I install fonts? (AskUbuntu.com)](https://askubuntu.com/q/3697/367990).

Then you may either be lucky and LibreOffice automatically recognizes that *EB-Garamond* is similar to *Garamond* and may replace it, or you have to set it manually. Therefore, you open any LibreOffice application (here: Writer) and select from the menu "Tools" > "Options..." to get the configuration window below, where you choose the section "LibreOffice/Fonts". Enable the checkbox "Apply replacement table" and enter the substitution rule you want in the listboxes above. You will have to write unknown fonts' names manually, but I think it will recognize it. Set the rule with a click on the green tick button and close the window with "OK".

[image]

More information on how Font-Fallback in LibreOffice/OpenOffice works, please visit [How do unknown fonts get substituted? (AskUbuntu.com)](https://askubuntu.com/q/653208/367990) and the article [What is Font Fallback (wiki.openoffice.org)](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Font-FAQ#Font_Fallback)

Comment: Good answer, but a question on the last portion.  My understanding is that the substitution is by "major class" of font (e.g., a standard substitution for any serif font that isn't installed).  If that's correct, installing a "knock-off" font wouldn't affect anything, unless the replacement font masquerades as the original.  Do you know what is the actual case (e.g., would EB-Garamont be substituted for Garamond)?

Comment: @fixer1234 I don't know, but that is indeed an interesting question. I posted that [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/653208/367990) and am waiting for an answer. As soon as I have one, I will include its most important contents here.

Comment: @fixer1234 Updated answer to include information about font fallback and substitution.

Comment: EB Garamond is available in the Ubuntu repositories, and can be installed with `apt-get install fonts-ebgaramond`.

Answer (score 0):

I added Garamond to LibreWriter by adding it to Firefox settings. I went into "General" in settings, then "Language and Appearance", then "Default Font", then selected "Garamond." When I went back to font choices in LibreWriter, there it suddenly was: Garamond. I know it's Garamond because i checked some of the unusual letter formations in that font.